# How do I show the health bars of enemies I have already scanned?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

If I use a Magic Lens on an enemy in battle I can see it's health bar for THAT battle and it's information is added to the Monster List. But it only appears for that battle. Is there any way for it to appear for all enemies in future battles after that point? Or do I need to scan every individual monster whose health bar I want every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way to do so. If you really want to know your ennemy's HP, you have to scan it again. Hopefully, the circumstances where you need to do so are rare (Bosses, or need to kill an enemy with a special attack)